# Google Maps Javascript API gives INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, ionic3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API from ionic 2 framework. This code

```
new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService().getPlacePredictions(
    { input: query, types: ['cities'] }, 
    function (predictions, status) {}
);
```

gives INVALID_REQUEST as a status and empty predictions.
In browser console I could see this URL query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1skha&4sen-US&9scities&15e3&key=my_api_key_is_here&callback=YYYY&token=XXXX
```

for `query=kha`.

Official documentation does not helps a lot (because there is no even error status returned).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, although it does not helps - I am using almost the same URL parameters as in your request (with my own API key) and places API is loaded before I am using getPlacePredictions (which does not require binding to HTML element). And it still gives the same error. In Google Console I've enabled Places Web API (as there is no API for JavaScript) and Maps API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking more closely in docs, I've found that I used incorrect type. It should be `'(cities)'` instead of `'cities'`.